# Multiple (Tomcat + ActiveMQ + Mysql) Transaction Management

Tags: spring, tomcat, transactions, activemq-classic, jta

We have Multiple Tomcat providing web services for our internal product.

**Tomcat, Active MQ servers are different**

Web services call sequence

1. Tomcat Receive request
2. Start DB Transaction (Spring Transaction)
3. Execute some business logic
4. Generate certain events & push in queue (Active MQ)

   Start JMS Transaction

   Push in queue

   Commit JMS
5. Execute other business logic

   (other business logic may generate another event for JMS)
6. Commit DB.

So what i want is to start Global Transaction which should take care of committing respective transaction in sequence.

JMS should only get commit if DB is getting commit.

Is it possible with JTA??????

Your suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  See these posts:

[Configuring Spring and JTA without full Java EE](http://blog.springsource.com/2011/08/15/configuring-spring-and-jta-without-full-java-ee)

[Configuring ActiveMQ transactions in Spring](http://www.jakubkorab.net/2011/08/configuring-activemq-transactions-in-spring.html)